# Is there a way to disallow "experimental" C++17 in CMake configuration?

Tags: cmake, c++17

I have set the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set (CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

However, CMake still allows g++ 6, even though it doesn't fully support c++17 (it has a c++1z standard, but not a c++17 standard).  Is there a way to tell CMake to only allow compilers that fully support the standard and not just pieces of it?

FWIW, I also tried setting cxx_relaxed_constexpr, which I think should have been the relevant language feature, but that still allowed g++ 6.  But it clearly can't compile code like

```
if constexpr (ENABLE_LOGGING) { do_loggy_stuff() };
```

So I'm not sure if there is a newer constexpr feature I should be looking for (there doesn't seem to be one in the latest cmake) or if CMake is just confused about what GCC 6 can do.

**Edit:** It seems I was slightly confused.  Even though GCC 6 doesn't document c++17 as a value of -std, it does accept it as a synonym for c++-1z.  So I guess what I'm looking for is a way to only look for "non-experimental" c++17 support.

Also, looking at the GCC documentation, it seems the feature I want is "constexpr if".  Unfortunately, CMake doesn't recognize `cxx_constexpr_if` or `cxx_if_constexpr` as valid compile features.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell CMake to only allow compilers that fully support the standard and not just pieces of it?

No. CMake does not have that information.