# g++ 6.3 enable relaxed constexpr

Tags: makefile, g++, c++17

I am using gcc 6.3.0 (specifically MinGW, though I want to support linux too). My code has working `constexpr` functions. A library I use uses a macro in function declarations with `constexpr` potential, which is only defined as `constexpr` when `__has_feature(cxx_relaxed_constexpr)`. Although I know that the library functions in question would work correctly with the macro defined, it is not defined as `constexpr` because apparently mingw g++ (and maybe real g++) does not have that feature enabled by default. I would like to make g++ enable that flag, hopefully via cli flag within the makefile, so I don't have to modify the library header.

`constexpr if` and/or `if constexpr` would be nice too, if possible.

The most relevant SO post I can find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332786/is-there-a-way-to-disallow-experimental-c17-in-cmake-configuration), which is unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a better time machine.

- GCC 6.3 was [released on](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) December 21, 2016.
- The C++17 standard was not released until the end of 2017.

This [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) says that `constexpr if` was first available in gcc 7.

Comment: Ok, I was looking at the [mingw download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version6/) which have it updated September 2017, but I guess it makes sense that mingw lagged behind real gcc. The problem is this is the latest version of mingw gcc. Other than VS/msbuild, is there anything modern port of c++ for windows?

Comment: Ugh... so the mingw installation manager was saying the "repository version" of mingw gcc was 6.3.0, which lined up with the sourceforge page. I just did a clean install and now I'm on 9.2.0. So apparently mingw's update pipeline has issues. Anyway, I'm now compiled past that problem.